# Scanf dentro do printf

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("digite um número %d",scanf("%d",&i));

}
```

O seguinte programa só dá o resultado 1 e não entendo o porquê.

Comment: Você pode selecionar o trecho de código e apertar `ctrl+k` para deixar formatado.

Answer (score 2):

Porque o *Scanf* retorna um inteiro com a quantidade de entradas.

```
scanf("%d",&i)
```

Esse vai retornar o número 1

```
scanf("%d" "%d",&p,&i)
```

Vai retornar o número 2 e assim por diante.

Se você colocar dentro de um `while`, da seguinte forma:

```
while ( scanf("%d", &i) == 1)
```

Vai ser true. Se colocar

```
while ( scanf ("%d" "%d", &p, &i) == 2)
```

Será `true` também.

E assim por diante.

Comment: Em C é correto você concatenar strings separando-as com espaço, agora, isso não é tradicional de se ver. No seu exemplo, na leitura de dois inteiros, eu esperaria encontrar `"%d %d"`, não `"%d" "%d"`. Repetindo, não está errado, só não é muito usual encontrar essa concatenação nas operações das famílias `scanf` e `printf`